# How to configure IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, intellisense, visual-studio-code, code-assist

How to configure IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code?

For example, lets consider the below code snippet.

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
```

I would like the IntelliSense to suggests the available methods on `React`, when I press `cmd + space` after typing `React.`.

Is that possible? If yes any pointer would be of great help.

**PS:**

I have already installed the `dependent modules` and updated the `package.json` and they are available at `./node_modules/`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/react

`tsd install react --save`

Restart, then, you can get intellisense

Comment: Looking forward to the resolution of [#957 - Intellisense for nodejs required packages](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/957). If vscode can do it w/o the explicit need to install `tsd`s, that would be great. There could be many modules w/o corresponding `tsd`s. For example, consider the parallel modules being developed.

Comment: parallel modules? do you mean [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/parallel)?

Comment: No really!! By parallel module, consider an `utility module` which is developed by your team in the same time frame as you are developing your `app`. Your `app` need this `utility module` as dependency.